# Pandas - how do I make a matrix from a list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've got a list of items. I want to make a matrix (or triangular matrix), where the rows and columns are items, and the matrix values are `f(x, y)`, where `f` is a function, and `x, y` are the indices.

If it's possible to use an implementation that supports parallel computation (i.e. map()), that's ideal.

What's the cleanest way?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

listofitems = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'grape']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.matrix(np.random.rand(4,4)), columns=listofitems, index=listofitems)
```

[image]

then to get your `f(x,y)` :

```
df['banana']['pear']
>> 0.34471005596459292
```

You can get it triangular with `np.triu` or `np.tril` eg

`df = pd.DataFrame(np.tril(np.matrix(np.random.rand(4,4))), columns=listofitems, index=listofitems)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `numpy.meshgrid()` to create a grid from a list and then evaluate a function on each cell.

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(a,a)
z = xx + yy
# out: array([[2, 3, 4, 5],
#             [3, 4, 5, 6],
#             [4, 5, 6, 7],
#             [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

you can also write more complicated functions:

```
def f(xx, yy):
    return np.sin(yy) + np.cos(xx)
z = f(xx, yy)
# out: array([[ 1.38177329,  0.42532415, -0.14852151,  0.18782736],
#             [ 1.44959973,  0.49315059, -0.08069507,  0.25565381],
#             [ 0.68142231, -0.27502683, -0.84887249, -0.51252361],
#             [-0.21650019, -1.17294933, -1.74679499, -1.41044612]])
```